# LINQ to XML selecting next node Elements

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am working on selecting some specfic data from an XML document.

Here is a sample of the xml document:

```
<data>
<variable name="somedata">
<row>
   <column>data</column> 
   <column>data</column> 
   <column>data</column> 
   <column>data</column> 
   <column>data</column>  
   <column>data</column>  
  </row>
 </variable>
 <variable name="CurrentSession">
  <row>
   <column>data I what to get</column> 
   <column>data I what to get</column> 
   <column />
  </row>
  <row>
   <column>data I what to get</column> 
   <column>data I what to get</column> 
   <column />
   </row>
 </variable>
</data>
```

I have decided to do it with Linq to XML.

This is what i have so far:

```
        var doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\CurrentSession.xml");
        var query = from d in doc.Descendants("row")
                    //where (string)d.Attribute("name") == ("CurrentSession")
                    select (string)d.Element("column");
        foreach (string name in query)
        {
            string xml = "test : " + name + "";
        }
```

My problem is that at the moment I'am getting all data from "column" I only what the data from "column" within the scope of `<variable name="currentSession">` But I am having difficulty jumping past the `<row>`

Can anyone help me figuring out how to skip the row node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you should first take your "variable", filter it by "where", and then take its row and column elements:

```
  var doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\CurrentSession.xml");
  var query = (from d in doc.Descendants("variable")
              where (string)d.Attribute("name") == "CurrentSession"
              select d.Elements("row")).First().Select(row => row.Element("column"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't terribly clear, but I *think* you just want:

```
var query = doc.Descendants("variable")
               .Where(v => (string) v.Attribute("name") == "CurrentSession")
               .Single()
               .Elements("row")
               .Select(row => (string) row.Element("column"));
```

Note that that assumes there's always a *single* `variable` element with a name of "CurrentSession", and that you really only want the value for the first column of each row.

If that's not what you need, you'll need to be clearer in your question.